Google Credential Manager not showing popup
I'm trying to implement the new Google Credential Manager in my app but, for some reason, the popup never appears. No errors, no warnings, nothing. Looking at the logs, it simply stops at "launching credentialManager". Everything else up to that point seems to be working fine.
This is my class:
class IntroTestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var b: ActivityIntroTestBinding
private lateinit var credentialManager: CredentialManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    b = ActivityIntroTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(b.root)

    credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)

    b.introImage.setOnClickListener {
        initializeGoogleSignIn()
    }
}

private fun initializeGoogleSignIn() {
    Log.d("errorTag", "initializeGoogleSignIn")
    val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val bytes = rawNonce.toByteArray()
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val digest = md.digest(bytes)
    val hashedNonce = digest.fold("") {str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it)}
   val googleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
       .setNonce(hashedNonce)
        .build()
    Log.d("errorTag", "googleIdOption ${googleIdOption.serverClientId}")
    val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
        .build()
    request.credentialOptions.forEach {
        Log.d("errorTag", "request ${it.type}")
    }

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        Log.d("errorTag", "launching credentialManager") // -> STOPS HERE!
        try {
            val result = credentialManager.getCredential(request = request, context = this@IntroTestActivity)
            val credential = result.credential
            val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)
            val googleIdToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                Toast.makeText(this@IntroTestActivity, "You are signed it! $googleIdToken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
            Log.d("errorTag", "GetCredentialException error = ${e.message}")
        } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
            Log.d("errorTag", "GoogleIdTokenParsingException error = ${e.message}")
        } catch (e: Error) {
            Log.d("errorTag", "Other error = ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}

I tried every tutorial, read all the documentation, followed each and every step including all the OAuth and ClientIDs. I've also tried to use "credentialManager.getCredentialAsync". Nothing seems to work. The popup where the user should select his account never appears.
PS: The app was using the old Google Sign In method and everything worked perfectly.

I still don't understand why I simply can't get the GetGoogleIdOption to work but if I use the GetSignInWithGoogleOption instead, everything seems to be working as expected.
All I needed to do was changing this:
val googleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
    .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
   .setNonce(hashedNonce)
    .build()

...into this:
val googleIdOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).build()

I hope this answer can help other devs that are facing the same problem because (sorry Google) the documentation is NOT very clear... at all.
